# What happens to Task Scheduler if User has no permission?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, administrative-privileges

I've a little question:
Lets say I have a Windows 2012 Server where I created a Scheduled Task with my Useraccount. I selected the option "Run this task even if user is not logged in" - so I don't have to be logged in the server that the task run.

Now, what would happen if someone takes my adminrights from the server, so that I can't log in at all? Will the Task still run? Since there was a "Use this Account for running the task" that I've selected, I'm not sure if the task would still run or not. I mean it should run since I've selected that I don't have to be logged in, but I'm not sure if it can still run the task with an account that has no longer permissions to connect to this server...

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things here. When you selected 'run when not logged in' did it ask for your password and save? If there was no error, then it should still be *able* to run. The next question is what is the trigger? Is a time, an eventlog entry, at logon? If there's no trigger it will not run unless somebody executes it manually. Third if somebody 'removes your admin rights' well that stops you from RDPing into the machine, by default members of the Admin group have RDP privilege. However, this will only affect your task if the task requires admin privileges to run.

TL;DR
If your job doesn't require admin, the trigger is still effective, and it saved your password (that isn't expired), yes it should run.